# Vector drawables not loading in xml ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, vector, bitmap

I am having trouble with loading vector files in my splash background xml file. The vector has been loaded successfully because I can open the vector file in android studio and I get a small graphic of the vector on the side of the xml file. However, the design view of the xml file shows an error for the vector file, and I get a ResourceNotFoundException when trying to run my app.

Code below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_loading_screen_logo"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[splash background.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbxvJ.jpg)

My grade version is `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'`

and I have included the following line in my grade app file `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

It seems that any vector file that I use has this error, so there is some setting of some sort that is missing.

Please assist in anyway.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is wrapping the xml drawable in a `<bitmap/>`

Try this:

**Replace**

```
<item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_loading_screen_logo"/>
</item>
```

**With:**

```
    <item android:gravity="center" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_screen_logo"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. replace `<bitmap`  to `<item`
2. make sure that your vector is in drawable folder not in drawable-24.
3. check vectory `path` may be its too long.